# lynx: relocation error

Tags: 18.04, cron, libraries, lynx, gnutls

Trying to run cron jobs with lynx fails. I get this error:

```
lynx: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
```

This is new after some recent updates. Anyone else experiencing this? Ideas how to solve? No new updates present.

```
Linux version 4.15.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~**18.04.1**)) #69-Ubuntu SMP Wed **Sep 4 20:55:53 UTC 2019**
```

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 | grep local` to the question. It seems that you have some self-compiled libraries as [gnutls or libidn2](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=_idn2_punycode_decode&literal=1). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Already mentioned versions in the question. Thanks for commenting! There was an update and there it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by downgrade of the lib like so:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
```